# Regex trouble with list comprehension

Tags: python, regex, list-comprehension

I am working in Python 3.7.6 on Windows and am attempting to use regex to transform one list of `foo.csv.gz` filenames into a list of the corresponding `foo.csv` filenames. A code snippet is below.

```
zippedFileNames = [re.search('[^/]*\\.gz', link).group(0) for link in linksList]

unzippedFileNames = [re.search('.*\\.csv', name).group(0) for name in zippedFileNames]
```

In the above code, `zippedFileNames` is a list created by isolating the `.gz` filenames from a list of download links. This line works as I expect, and taking `zippedFileNames[0]` returns a string. The type of `zippedFileNames[0]` is `str` and the type of `zippedFileNames` is `list`.

However, the code throws an error on the second line:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
  File "H:\foo\bar\foobar.py", line 133, in <listcomp>
    x = [re.search('.*\\.csv', name).group(0) for name in zippedFileNames]
  File "H:\foo\bar\foobar.py", line 133, in <module>
    x = [re.search('.*\\.csv', name).group(0) for name in zippedFileNames]
```

This code was working yesterday but stopped working today, and I am not sure what I changed to break it. I believe it broke after I tried amending the second line's `pattern` to omit the  first digits and underscore using the pattern `'[^0-9\\_].*\\.csv'` (the filenames all follow a pattern `0000_foo_bar_foobar.csv.gz`). However, even reverting the pattern to the old one before the omission does not solve my problem.

Is there something I'm not seeing?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Thank you for your answers.

I checked whether there is a `None` in my list both by printing all list items and by using `print(None in zippedFileNames)`. The latter test returned `False` and the former returned all the items as I'm expecting. I also did not find `None` in my linksList.

When I run the regex `re.search` on just one of the elements of `linksList`, `linksList[0]`, I get the correct string output.

Are there other things I can try?

**EDIT 2:**

I tried re-using the original regex pattern `'[^/]*\\.gz'` in a separate call and it worked. Then I also tried using the pattern `'[^/]*\\.csv\\.gz'` in hopes of getting the same result as I got with the former pattern, but this pattern returned an error as well. I'm suspecting that the errors have something to do with `\\.csv`.

**RESOLUTION**
I was matching on `.csv`, but it turned out that I had a `.report` file as well, and that one was throwing off the entire script. Iterating through matches helped to isolate the issue. To solve the regex, I matched the pattern `'.*\\[^.gz]'` to keep all file extensions, not just `.csv`. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Look, you need no regex if all you need is check if a string contains `.csv`, just use `unzippedFileNames = [name for name in zippedFileNames if '.csv' in name]`. See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/yGUckb).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's a neat trick I didn't know about. However, my goal is to extract the ```foo.csv``` filename from the ```0000_foo.csv.gz``` filename. That's why I approached the problem using regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I was matching on ```.csv```, but it turned out that I had a ```.report``` file as well, and that one was throwing off the entire script. Iterating through matches helped to isolate the issue. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
zippedFileNames=['0001_foo1.csv', 'def.bz', '0000_foo2.csv.gz']
unzippedFileNames = []
for name in zippedFileNames:
  m = re.match(r"\d+_(.*\.csv)", name)
  if m:
    unzippedFileNames.append(m.group(1))
print(unzippedFileNames)
# => ['foo1.csv', 'foo2.csv']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/AsRB6q).

Here, the `unzippedFileNames` is declared as an empty list. Then, iterating over the `zippedFileNames`, each name is checked against a `\d+_(.*\.csv)` regex (note that `re.match` only searches for a match at the start of the string), and if there is a match (`if m:`) the Group 1 contents are appended to the `unzippedFileNames` list.

Answer (score 1):

[`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) returns `None` if the string doesn't match . Your second regex seems wrong. I think it should be `'.*\.csv`. You can test it with [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

[EDIT]: You regex is correct, you probably have a file which doesn't match the regex in `zippedFileName`

Comment: What is wrong with the second regex? There is nothing wrong with it. It is just the same what you suggest.

Comment: Indeed I forgot you that you need to escape the backslash with a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is an None or empty value in the lists that you are using, zippedFileNames or linksList.